# Parity configuration for rinkeby testnet

Tags: parity, testnets, configuration, rinkeby

Can someone provide me an genesis block configuration json for Parity client here is my setup described:

I've installed the client (version: **Parity/v1.6.8-beta-c396229-20170608/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.17.0**). Converted my rinkeby genesis block config using this as input:www.rinkeby.io/rinkeby.json and using this tool mentioned on the github wiki page: https://github.com/keorn/parity-spec. Which resulted in this config file: https://gist.github.com/kgcorps/3b67338bc5ea204372f993ed25389e88

When trying to start parity with the following command:

```
parity --chain=res.json --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303 --identity=foobar --datadir=$HOME/.rinkebyParity
```

I have hunch I've made stupid mistake somewhere with the config conversion. The source config is good to go since I've used it with geth without any problems.

Thanks for any tips

**Edit**
As far as I understand parity doesn't support ProofOfAuthority algorithm, does this mean that it is impossible to use parity with rinkeby testnet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parity does very well support [proof of authority](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Proof-of-Authority-Chains), but it does not implement the `Clique` engine required to join the Rinkeby test network. It just wont work out.

If you want to join a PoA testnet, you can still use [Kovan](https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal):

```
parity --chain kovan
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, already switched to kovan. And run some tests :)

Answer (score 0):

You can now join rinkeby with parity, with my version of parity: https://github.com/thefallentree/parity-clique , just download , build and run parity --chain rinkeby